# JQuery: Prepending a form to a <tr>

Tags: jquery, forms, html-table, var, prepend

I have a html table and I want to append a form to each tr. I have written this:

```
<script>

var bform = '<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get"><input type="hidden" value="event"></input><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></from>';

$('tr').prepend(bform);

</script>
```

But it does not seem to be working for me, nor is it throwing an error in the console.

Could some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where is this script tag in your HTML? Is it after your `tr`'s? It could be a case of the DOM not being ready yet?

Comment: the closing tag on your string is `</from>` not `</form>`. Also, you cannot append/prepend to a `tr`. You must use a `td`. Also, `input` tags are self-closing, you don't need `</input>`.

Comment: Is this code wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `tr` and `td` to your `bform`

```
var bform = '<tr><td> YOUR FORM HERE</td></tr>'
```

When you prepend a string to a `tr`, you are inserting inside a `table`, so, your current code is invalid:

```
<table>
    <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" value="event"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </from>';
    ^^^^^ INVALID HTML ^^^^^

    <tr>
        <td>CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As Blender said, make sure you put the code inside a `jQuery(document).ready(function($){})`

Additionally, you don't need to close `inputs`, so, both are valid codes:

```
<input type="hidden" value="event">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Thanks -  I wwas missing quite a bit! Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you execute it after jQuery and the DOM are loaded:

```
$(function(){
    $('tr').prepend(bform);
});
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').prepend(bform);
});
```

Also you have a typo where your closing `</form>` tag is `</from>`